# Sudo asking for password

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am new in `Jenkins CI` development, Tying to setup Jenkins on Linux system for that I have [referring site](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions)

But, when I type provided url `sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jen` it giving me following issue

```
bld064870199 btwnpmd01 $sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jen
Password:
btwnpmd011 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I have put my server password but It is not working can some body help me which password it asking for or how can I setup Jenkins on Linux system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the sudo password prompt you should enter the password of the current user. Additionaly the user needs to be granted rights to execute commands through sudo.

You need something like below in your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
btwnpmd011  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Judging by the username and hostname of the system you have a Unix operations department. If you do, it's best to tell them what you want to do and they can arrange it for you.

Comment: In my windows system I have used .war file, deployed that file in weblogic server, It's worked for me. but can we do same on Linux

Comment: This is a different question that the original question. SuperUser's format is Q&A, not forum-style. Please create a [new question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask). Also, if my answer answered your question, please click the green check mark next to the answer so people know your question has been answered.